# How do ADC/DACs deal with out of sync signals near Nyquist frequency?

Tags: sampling, nyquist

Let's say a converter is sampling continuously at 48 kHz and the incoming waveform is a sine wave at 24 kHz... How does it faithfully recreate the waveform if the samples are taken at points that are 0?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does it faithfully recreate the waveform if the samples are taken a points that are 0?

Not at all. Things at $\frac{f_\text{sample}}2$ might just as well be constants. You can't tell [0 0 0 0] (sampled 24 kHz signal at zero-crossings) from [0 0 0 0] (sampled zero constant signal).

Nor can you tell [0.1 -0.1 0.1 -0.1] (sampled 24 kHz signal with amplitude 1 just a bit after each zero-crossing) from [0.1 -0.1 0.1 -0.1] (sampled 24 kHz signal of amplitude 0.1, sampled at its extrema!).

You need the sampling rate to be *higher* (not only *just as high*) than two times the highest signal frequency component for this to be unambiguous.

Comment: That's what i was thinking also.. but after watching a video on why higher sample rates don't matter in audio production, i came away confused as the speaker seemed to suggest that samples not perfectly [1 -1 1 -1] can still be recreated perfectly at output. I'll leave link here for anyone how is interested (6:40): https://xiph.org/video/vid2.shtml

Comment: Watch closely! 7:25: "if it differs even minutely, it's got frequency content **at** or beyond Nyquist…" So, having frequency components at Nyquist frequency introduces an error

Answer (score 1):

That's why practical sampling operations that uses ADCs employ sampling frequencies about 10 percent higher (if not M times oversampling deliberately) than that's given by the theoretical limit of Nyquist rate which is twice the bandwidth. This is further supported by proper **anti-aliasing** filtering which would suppress enough at the stop band so that no significand content remains at the edges of the input signal's bandwidth of interest.